# Find a function for $\theta$ from the equation $2\sin\theta+\cos\theta+D\frac{D\sin\theta}{2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}-2\sin\theta\cos\theta=1+C$

Tags: trigonometry

Is following equation Transcendental equation? Or is there a way to find a function for theta using programming or something else?

$$2\sin\theta+\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}+D\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})-\sin2\theta=1+C$$
I was trying to solve it following way,

$$2\sin\theta+\cos\theta+D\frac{D\sin\theta}{2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}-2\sin\theta\cos\theta=1+C$$
$$2\sin\theta(1+\cos\theta)+\cos\theta(1+\frac{D\sin\theta}{2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\theta})=1+C$$
$$2\sin\theta(1+\cos\theta)+\cos\theta(1+\frac{D\sin\theta}{\dfrac{\cos\theta}{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}})=1+C$$

I can't move on. I can't see any way to solve it.

Comment: How large are $C$ and $D$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici they are Just constant. We can consider C and D is 0 to ∞.

Comment: No more than $\infty$ ? I am typing something.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici is there really any number after Infinity? With my current mind, i can't think any number which is bigger than infinity. I know that everyone describes infinity differently, whenever I say ∞ I actually tryna say that "I am talking about number which we can't describe using Pen or Notepad. No matter how much 0 u write after 1. You never can reach ∞".

Answer (score 1):

Admitting that you look for a zero of function
$$f(\theta)=2 \sin (\theta)+\cos (\theta)+D \sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)-\sin (2 \theta)-(C+1)$$ the solution is bounded between the roots of
$$g(\theta)=2 \sin (\theta)+\cos (\theta)-\sin (2 \theta)-(C+1-D)=0$$ and
$$h(\theta)=2 \sin (\theta)+\cos (\theta)-\sin (2 \theta)-(C+1+D)=0$$ Using the tangent half-angle substitution $\theta=2 \tan ^{-1}(x)$, just to get bounds, we would need to solve for $x$ two equations
$$\frac{-x^4+8 x^3+1}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}=k\qquad \text{where} \qquad k=C+1\pm D$$ which is doable with radicals but very tedious (and just to bound the solution !).

Using the quadruple angle formula $\theta=4 \tan ^{-1}(y)$ would lead to the monster (an octic polynomial).

So, let us discard such approaches.

Now, considering some iterative method, notice that we have
$$f(0)=-C \qquad \qquad f'(0)=\frac D 2\qquad \qquad f''(0)=-1$$ So, since $f(0)\times f''(0)>0$, by Darboux theorem, Newton method should converge without any overshoot of the solution.
$$\theta_0=0 \implies \theta_1=\frac{2 C}{D}$$ and we can repeat the process using
$$\theta_{n+1}=\theta_{n}-\frac {f(\theta_{n})}{f'(\theta_{n})}$$

Trying for $C=3$ and $D=7$, we should have for following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \theta_n \\
 0 & 0.85714286 \\
 1 & 0.83580616 \\
 2 & 0.83574456
\end{array}
\right)$$

However, there is a problem : we must have a root before reaching a maximum.

*For the time being, I did not find the condition.*

Comment: My friend (who found that equation) is saying that C and D is constant. And they are height, iirc. D is height of a man. I think we can consider the range of C and D between 0 to 10000

Comment: And +1 to see the  answer